# Problem setting different log levels for different namespaces using NLog

Tags: .net-core, configuration, nlog

I'm having problem getting the nlog configuration correct for a dotnet core 7 application.

The objective is to get logs from Microsoft namespaces to be at the Warn level or higher and all other logs to be at the Info level or higher.

Here is the config as of now

```
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="ownFile-web,database" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minLevel="Warn" writeTo="ownFile-web,database" final="true" />
  </rules>
```

When running the application the internal nlog file generates a lot of output like this `Logger: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ApplicationLifetime configured with duplicate output to target: FileTarget(Name=ownFile-web). LoggingRule with NamePattern='Microsoft.*' and Level=Warn has been skipped.`

I've been fiddling back and forth but I can't get it right. Please help!

Comment: The order of the [NLog Logging Rules](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules) are important. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Rules-FinalMinLevel